# send datatable from a page to another one in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, web

i have a datatable that i get it from sql,and after some process on each row i add a column to the datatable that shows the process result and then i want to send it to another page in asp.net ,what is the best way? 
is it ok to use session or what?

i try it with session but i'm not sure that it is ok,because many people use my server.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("img", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("soratvaziat", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("shomaregharardad", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("sharh", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("eghdam", typeof (Boolean));


        DataRow dtrow = dt.NewRow();    // Create New Row
        dtrow["img"] = "accepted.png";            //Bind Data to Columns
        dtrow["soratvaziat"] = "SureshDasari";
        dtrow["shomaregharardad"] = "B.Tech";
        dtrow["sharh"] = "Chennai";
        dtrow["eghdam"] = true;
        dt.Rows.Add(dtrow);

        dtrow = dt.NewRow();               // Create New Row
        dtrow["img"] = "attention.png";               //Bind Data to Columns
        dtrow["soratvaziat"] = "MadhavSai";
        dtrow["shomaregharardad"] = "MBA";
        dtrow["sharh"] = "Nagpur";
        dtrow["eghdam"] = true;

        dt.Rows.Add(dtrow);

        dtrow = dt.NewRow();              // Create New Row
        dtrow["img"] = "canceled.png";              //Bind Data to Columns
        dtrow["soratvaziat"] = "MaheshDasari";
        dtrow["shomaregharardad"] = "B.Tech";
        dtrow["sharh"] = "Nuzividu";
        dtrow["eghdam"] = true;

        dt.Rows.Add(dtrow);

        dtrow = dt.NewRow();              // Create New Row
        dtrow["img"] = "accepted.png";              //Bind Data to Columns
        dtrow["soratvaziat"] = "Mahendra";
        dtrow["shomaregharardad"] = "CA";
        dtrow["sharh"] = "Guntur";
        dtrow["eghdam"] = false;

        dt.Rows.Add(dtrow);
        RadGrid1.DataSource = dt;
        RadGrid1.DataBind();
        Session["dt"] = dt;
```

Comment: You are not able to make an insert for new row in SQL, and in another page make another query for all inserted rows? This is the best choice when you have a database. Is better making multiple inserts and selects for a single user, than storing a lot of data in session

Comment: Do you keep client specific data on your datatable?

Comment: Don't store datatable in session. bad bad bad. too bloated, too heavy and if you are storing large objects in session then you need to re-think your approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with the PreviousPage property. This allows you to access variables from the page that sent control to the currently loaded page. You need to set a couple things up in your .ASPX page directive, but then you use

```
PreviousPage.Something
```

To do it. I'd set the datatable up as a property and refer to that property on the current page.

For further reading:

[Passing values across ASPX pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Does this work with Response.Redirect or do I have to post on the target page?

Answer (score 1):

if session is not enabled then you context to send data

```
Context.Items.Add("context name", DataTable);
```

and you can access it from the another page by

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)Context.Items["context name"];
```

Answer (score -5):

1- create a class

2- put into your class a `public static DataTable dataTable`

3- then put your dataTable variable to it;

4- you can restore it from any where.

Comment: That is even worse than `Cache` suggested in the other answer. `static` is also application wide so shared across all users but you are also introducing threading issues.

Comment: @EmanuelPirovano if it is then why didn't you down vote it? Or if you think it can be improved offer that advice.